# helm chaining multiple conditions

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have this following condition in my template:

```yaml
spec:
{{- if and (not .Values.first.param)  ( not .Values.second.param) }}
  type: NodePort
{{- else }}
  type: ClusterIP
```

I need to add 2 more conditions, so I've tried the following code:

```yaml
spec:
{{- if and (not .Values.first.param)  ( not .Values.second.param) (not eq .Values.port "80") (not eq .Values.port "443") }}
  type: NodePort
{{- else }}
  type: ClusterIP
```

When I test it, it is failing with the following error:

`at <not>: wrong number of args for not: want 1 got 3`

What is the correct way to combine the new conditions with the existing ones?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to use `ne` instead of `not eq`:

```yaml
{{- if and (not .Values.first.param)  ( not .Values.second.param) (ne .Values.port "80") (ne .Values.port "443") }}
```